Has anyone used stream-chat-expo with Expo SDK 51 successfully?
The example is still pointing to Expo SDK 50, when I build the android binary I'm getting

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-av'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

and

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

The iOS binary builds and works as expected.
I found this guy who hard coded the compileSdkVersion for expo-image-manipulator and expo-image-picker .. which steam-chat-expo requires .. so just wondering if anyone has used stream-chat-expo with Expo SDK 51 yet ..

I got the android binary build to work .. but I had to include several libraries that stream-chat-expo had declared as optional, because it was pulling them in at a lower version .. and there for giving me the compileSdkVersion error.  I had to add expo-av, expo-document-picker, expo-haptics, and expo-sharing.
